maintainer_mode configure option - is it still operational?
This suggest that the --enable-maintainer-mode still should work.
However, when I try to pass it to configure I am getting:
configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --enable-maintainer-mode.
What is wrong? Am I looking at the wrong/old documentation?

Quick comment on whether you should add AM_MAINTAINER_MODE to avoid that warning: Don't.  Maintainer mode made sense in the 1990s and the early 2000s when local storage space, network access, and package managers were often limited. So risking broken builds (maintainer mode disabled) was worth the tradeoff of not having to download and install extra build tools like autoconf and automake.  In 2024, build machines do not have those limitations.  So if you have changed the sources and now need the build tools to remake part of the build system, you can do so quickly and easily.  Do that.


when I try to pass it to configure I am getting:
configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --enable-maintainer-mode.

What is wrong?

As the docs you linked describe, you must have the AM_MAINTAINER_MODE macro in your configure.in for maintainer-mode management to be available (otherwise, maintainer mode is on by default and cannot be disabled).  The warning you present suggests that either you have not included that macro, or you have not re-run auto[re]conf since adding it.

Am I looking at the wrong/old documentation?

The link in your question appears to be to the current docs.
